# MSYS2でインストールしたPythonがコマンドプロンプトで使えない（PATH適応済み）

Tags: python, windows, msys2

今日MSYS2を使って`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python`コマンドを実行し`C:\msys64\migw64\bin`にPythonをインストールしました（PATHは該当ディレクトリに設定してあります）しかし、コマンドプロンプトで`python`と実行すると、何故かストアアプリが開いてしまいます。

なお、同ディレクトリには`python3.8`なる実行形式ファイルも含まれており、こちらをタイプしてみた所正常にREPLが起動しましたが、もう片方の`python3`なる実行形式ファイルを実行しました所またもストアアプリが開いてしまいました。

これはWindws10の仕様でしょうか？また解決策はあるのでしょうか？VScodeでRustをデバックする際に3.3以上のPythonが必要になるようで、どうしても解決したいと思っています

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows での Python の使用についてよく寄せられる質問](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/python/faqs#why-does-running-pythonexe-open-the-microsoft-store)で説明されています。

> ## python.exe を実行すると Microsoft Store が開くのはなぜですか?
>
> 新しいユーザーが Python の適切なインストールを見つけられるよう、Microsoft Store で公開されているコミュニティのパッケージの最新バージョンに直結したショートカットを Windows に追加しました。 このパッケージは、管理者のアクセス許可がなくても簡単にインストールでき、既定の `python` および `python3` コマンドを実際のものに置き換えます。
> コマンドライン引数を指定してショートカットの実行可能ファイルを実行すると、Python がインストールされていないことを示すエラー コードが返されます。 これは、意図していない場合にバッチ ファイルおよびスクリプトによって Store アプリが開かれるのを防ぐためです。
> python.org のインストーラーを使用して Python をインストールし、"PATH に追加" オプションを選択した場合、新しい `python` コマンドがショートカットよりも優先されます。 他のインストーラーは、組み込みのショートカットよりも_低い_優先度で `python` を追加する場合があることに注意してください。
> Python をインストールせずにショートカットを無効にするには、[スタート] から [Manage app execution aliases] (アプリ実行エイリアスの管理) を開き、"App Installer" (アプリ インストーラー) Python エントリを見つけて "オフ" に切り替えます。

とあるように、python.org 以外のものを使用したため、PATHの指定が不適切で正しく動作しなかったと考えられます。手順が示されているように設定からPythonの項目を無効化できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Pythonは門外漢なので助かりました。しかしMSのサポートページにあったとは迂闊でした。

Answer (score 0):

これはPATHの順番を変えることで解決できます｡
`C:\msys64\migw64\bin`が`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`より上に来るようにしてください｡
[image: alt]